# Alterar nome de elementos

Tags: c#, web-service, xml, wcf

Gostaria de esclarecer algumas dúvidas uma vez que não tenho muita experiência com Web-Services e, atualmente, fui encarregado de rever e implementar algumas mudanças em um sistema já implantado. Pela inexperiência, ando enfrentando dificuldades básicas para entender e modificar determinados trechos do código conferido a mim.

**O problema**: Preciso mapear adequadamente os elementos de resposta para determinada operação. O objeto de resposta é constituído pelos seguintes elementos:

```
<operacaoResponse xmlns="namespace">
    <sucesso xmlns="namespace"></sucesso>
    <mensagem xmlns="namespace"></mensagem>
    <documento xmlns="namespace">
                                 ...</documento>
</operacaoResponse>
```

onde `<documento>` é um elemento complexo.

A classe que implementa tal objeto encontra-se codificada da seguinte forma:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="operacaoResponse", WrapperNamespace="namespace", IsWrapped=true)]
    public partial class operacaoResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="namespace", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="namespace")]
    public bool sucesso;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="namespace", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="namespace")]
    public string mensagem;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="namespace", Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="namespace")]
    public Package.tipoDocumento documento;
```

O objeto documento deve ser formatado da seguinte forma:

```
<documento>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
</documento>
```

E a classe "tipoDocumento" encontra-se implementada da seguinte forma:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="namespace")]
public partial class tipoDocumento {

    private tipoA aField;

    private tipoB[] bField;

    private tipoC[] cField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public tipoA aField {
        get {
            return this.aField;
        }
        set {
            this.aField = value;
        }
    }
...
```

**Minha dúvida é**: como fazer com que a property aField possa ser mapeada seguindo o padrão xml descrito anteriormente? Me refiro à nomenclatura dos elementos. Mesmo quando especifico um XmlElement à property e defino um novo ElementName as informações são geradas seguindo a nomenclatura original da property.

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName="a", Order="0")
    public tipoA aField {
        get {
            return this.aField;
        }
        set {
            this.aField = value;
        }
    }
```